# Isn't a language construct just syntax?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

From the tag wiki on [language-construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-construct):

> A language construct is a syntactically allowable part of a program that may be formed from one or more lexical tokens in accordance with the rules of a programming language.
>
> In simpler terms, it is the syntax/way a programming language is written. However we do not recommend using this tag in this general semantic meaning as the general keyword syntax would fit it better.

I don't understand the difference between this tag and [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax). Can someone explain the difference to me?

Comment: Related: [What does 'Language Construct' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10057524/290085)

Answer (score 27):

The 53 questions under [language-construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-construct) seem to be quite diverse both in terms of topic and post quality. As someone pointed out, the term seems to have a specific meaning in the context of PHP, but probably not elsewhere(?). 22 questions are tagged [language-construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-construct) + [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

I think this tag should just get removed, not made a synonym. If it is a useful tag for PHP questions, then maybe a separate tag should be created for that purpose. [php-language-construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-language-construct)?

Comment: It does have a specific meaning in the context of PHP, but many of the PHP questions tagged with it really are just asking about syntax rather than that meaning.

Comment: @Don'tPanic So maybe some other existing tag would more suitable for such, like for example [tag:language-lawyer]? Which is often used when looking for formal syntax and definitions.

Comment: "specific meaning in the context of PHP" - I don't think it does. The PHP docs explicitly reference "language constructs" in order to explain certain function-like syntax (and behaviour), but the meaning of "language construct" is really the same as in any programming language. [PHP: What are language constructs and why do we need them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254327/php-what-are-language-constructs-and-why-do-we-need-them)

Answer (score 13):

I would have said that a language construct is an abstraction. For example many languages have an `if-else` construct, but this is separate from syntax as that is language-specific. You are able to talk about `if-else` statements without going into the specific syntax (e.g. talking about JavaScript's parenthesis or curly braces).

I think the value of this tag is when asking questions that are somewhat language-agnostic. But in those instances I'm not sure if SO rules would define that as 'too broad'...

Comment: So basically you mean `language-construct` is the `meta-syntax`?

Comment: I think `meta-syntax` is a bit of a confusing term. Is that the syntax of syntax? `language-construct` can refer to more general concepts that I think fall outside any definition of syntax

Comment: No it isn't meta-syntax.  Metasyntax is basically a language used to express a syntax; e.g. EBNF is a metasyntax.  But I think that Tom is missing the point in saying it is an abstraction.  A language construct is really a *syntax* and some *semantics*.  The semantics are (informally) "what the construct does or means", and will typically be stated in the language specification.  The language designers *could* even go to the extent of expressing the semantics formally; e.g. using "denotational semantics" notation.

Answer (score 10):

To fully understand what [language-construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-construct) means, I think we should rather discuss the `language-construct` as a word first, instead of inspecting current questions with this tag. According to **Information technology - Vocabulary [ISO/IEC 2382:2015](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:2382:ed-1:v1:en)** this is what the word means:

> **syntactically allowable part of a program that may be formed from one or more lexical tokens in accordance with the rules of a programming language**

This definition may seem formal, but IMO it can be loosely softened down to any type of these:

- Control flow
- Expressions
- Compiler directive
- Assembler directive
- Variable declaration
- Function call
- String/Text format
- etc

So in other words `syntax` defines how words are combined to create phrases or sentences and a `language-construct` is the result of that syntax, a set of phrases or sentences created according to the syntax is the `language-construct`.

I think [language-construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-construct) is not a synonym to either [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) or [php-language-construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-language-construct). It may have a special meaning in PHP, but I don't think it's fair to narrow down it to PHP.

Maybe one reason that questions under this tag are rather low is that discussion about the internal working of a programming language syntax and how something is constructed using that syntax is rarely taken place in SO and is more in specific private mailing-list or recently for some open-source languages in GitHub issues or specific websites of said language.

There's also [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10057916/15055605) related to this, which explains with a real-world example.

Comment: Personally I don't think the example used in the answer you linked to is particularly useful or valid since a language construct doesn't exist as a term in natural language linguistics. Syntax in that case is synonymous with rules. But nonetheless I agree with your verdict.

Comment: Have an upvote for your effort. I don't think the tag will ever be used like this though :)

Answer (score 2):

The tag might have some value for nontrivial language constructs. For instance, C++ has the ["Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp). For historical reasons, the term "pattern" is used here, but "construct" would fit as well.

Why is this **more** than just syntax? The C++ syntax allows the use of any valid class template instantiation as a base class. CRTP specifically refers to a language construct where that class template has the *derived* class as a template parameter.

In general, most programming languages have a very rich syntax. Specific *language constructs* can describe common patterns where the syntax is used is a specific way.

Compare design patterns, which are usually language-agnostic.

Comment: Isn't that overly specific? Why not just tag with [tag:design-patterns] and a language?

Comment: @PasserBy: CRTP is not a _design pattern_, it's a bit of an oddball language use pattern that revealed itself in the 1990s (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).  I'm not being facetious in my use of _revealed_ here.

Comment: Language-specific patterns are called [idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/idioms/info).

Comment: @jaco0646 Are all language-specific patterns called idioms, or just those that are good practice and not e.g. antipatterns?

Comment: Isn't the CRTP just a different name for what everybody else calls F-bounded quantification in parametric polymorphism?

Comment: @jaco0646 I'd say when comparing to natural languages, in my mind, "language construct" translates to "grammar point": a specific rule in syntax. Whereas those give limits, and thus shape, a language, idioms are use patterns within those constraints. "transitive verb sentence" is a grammar point, and `whileLoop: while ( <expr> ) <body>` is a language construct; "kick the bucket" (="to die") is an idiom, and so is `!!~str.indexOf(substr)` (="is substr present in str"). I would not call the former an idiom; and neither the latter a language construct (except insomuchas "expression" is one).

Comment: That said, a question about language constructs (at least in my usage) is also a question about syntax, so I don't see the point of the tag.